# Cinder can not create volume types

Tags: juju, openstack

I am setting up MAAS+JUJU+Ubuntu 14.04 based Openstack setup.
I have configured all the Openstack services as JUJU charms.

On a fresh installation,when I am trying to create a Volume type, 
the message is displayed saying "Error: Unable to create volume type"

I found this entry in the `/var/log/cinder/cinder-volume.log` which
may point to the potential problem.

But I am unable to root cause the problem from this information.

```
2014-12-04 09:36:07.157 19047 TRACE cinder.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
2014-12-04 09:36:07.157 19047 TRACE cinder.openstack.common.threadgroup     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
2014-12-04 09:36:07.157 19047 TRACE cinder.openstack.common.threadgroup   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
2014-12-04 09:36:07.157 19047 TRACE cinder.openstack.common.threadgroup     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
2014-12-04 09:36:07.157 19047 TRACE cinder.openstack.common.threadgroup OperationalError: (OperationalError) (1130, "Host '10.50.0.4' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server") None None
2014-12-04 09:36:07.157 19047 TRACE cinder.openstack.common.threadgroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Log does clearly indicates that the problem is with db acess. When db user is created, you can define from where that user is allowed to connect. As it is juju that configured db, you should check charm documentation, whether you should pass some extra config to charm to indicate how db is supposed to be configured. I think I had similar issues when configured some services on same host as db, juju recognized it and configured database to allow only connections through local socket. Solution was removing everything and installing services in lxc ( juju deploy --to lxc:0 mysql ).